# Issue in MAKE command

Tags: spss

I am trying to restructure one .sav file using VARSTOCASES command and i got one syntax from IBM site,but i didn't get any examples for the same so i tried with some variables but its not working,Can anyone help for this

Actual Syntax from IBM Site

```
VARSTOCASES

/MAKE new variable ["label"] [FROM] varlist [/MAKE ...]

[/INDEX = {new variable ["label"]                                  }]
      {new variable ["label"] (make variable name)             }
      {new variable ["label"] (n) new variable ["label"](n) ...}

[/ID = new variable ["label"]]

[/NULL = {DROP**}]
     {KEEP  }

[/COUNT=new variable ["label"]]

[/KEEP={ALL**  }] [/DROP=varlist] 
   {varlist}
```

My code

```
GET
FILE='D:\SPSStoCSV\FileFormator\bin\FILES\Argentina\Temp.sav'.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.

VARSTOCASES
/MAKE new variable VariableName1 [FROM] varlist [/MAKE  Purchp6m_2 Purchp6m_4]

[/INDEX = {new variable VariableName1                                  }]
      {new variable VariableName1 (make variable name)             }
      {new variable VariableName1 (3) new variable VariableName1(3) ...}

[/ID = new variable VariableName1]
[/NULL = {DROP**}]
         {KEEP  }
[/COUNT=new variable VariableName1]

[/KEEP={ALL**  }] [/DROP=varlist] 
     {varlist}.

SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='C:\Users\10522\Desktop\Temp.csv'
/TYPE=CSV
/ENCODING='UTF8'
/MAP
/REPLACE
/FIELDNAMES
/CELLS=VALUES.
```

here i want to keep all the variables except these 2(Purchp6m_2 Purchp6m_4)in KEEP command,Here i have some 150 variables so instead of keeping all the 148 variable names in the KEEP command i am trying like All** and DROP command, but this is giving all data without restructuring any of the variables.I am trying to avoid adding all the remaining variables in the KEEP command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the square and the curly brackets `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`. They are used on IBM website only to signal optional arguments and lists of variables; they are not part of the syntax itself.

Second, you cannot use spaces in your variable names, so `new variable`should be `new_variable`

Third, you are using `new_variable` multiple times, which is wrong. you need to assign actual names to those variables.

Your code needs to be something like this: (although it is not very clear neither to me, and probably nor to you, why you need all the optional arguments):

```
GET
FILE='D:\SPSStoCSV\FileFormator\bin\FILES\Argentina\Temp.sav'.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.

VARSTOCASES
/MAKE Purchp6m "Purchp6m" FROM Purchp6m_2 Purchp6m_4
/INDEX = index_variable "Index variable"
/ID = id_variable "Variable ID"
/NULL = KEEP
/COUNT=count_variable "Count VAriable"
/KEEP=ALL.
EXECUTE.

SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='C:\Users\10522\Desktop\Temp.csv'
/TYPE=CSV
/ENCODING='UTF8'
/MAP
/REPLACE
/FIELDNAMES
/CELLS=VALUES.
```

`KEEP=ALL` is the default, so you don't actually need to specify it

Comment: here i don't want to KEEP all the variables i need to keep all the variables except these two(Purchp6m_2 and Purchp6m_4),So instead of typing all the remaining variables in KEEP, if there is any way to make it simple

Comment: 'drop=all' instead of keep subcommand should delete all other variables

Comment: i don't want to drop all the variables i need to drop only these two(Purchp6m_2 Purchp6m_4) which are included in the MAKE.

Comment: the command is making a new variable from these two, so they will not exist in the restructured data - no need for `drop` or `keep`.

Comment: `DROP` and `KEEP` subcommands refer to the other variables, not involved in any `MAKE` subcommand. `Purchp6m_2` and `Purchp6m_4` will not be included in the output, because they are restructured into `Purchp6m`.

Comment: just assume we have 150 variables, then if I want to unpivot all 148 variables except 2 variable (Purchp6m_2 Purchp6m_4), how do I need to change my code.
Can I do this without putting all 148 variables in MAKE

Comment: yes, just ignore the KEEP and DROP arguments; just don't put them in your syntax

Comment: on that time it will keep all 150 variables,i want to KEEP only 148 variables

Comment: are you saying you have run the syntax as I suggested and you still have `Purchp6m_2` and `Purchp6m_4` in your data ?